# How can I make my DIVs appear below each other

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<div style="float: left; padding-right: 1%;">
  <label class="editor-label" for="BrowserTitle">Browser Title</label>
  <input class="editor-field" id="BrowserTitle" name="Question.BrowserTitle" size="30" type="text" value="Test title" />
</div>
```

I want to make the input field appear below the label. Right now it just follows the label on the same line. Is there a way that I can do this with CSS?

Comment: use `display:block` on `<label>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set

```
display: block;
```

on either the label or the input.

**Note:** As pointed out in a comment, you'd also need to remove the `float` style from your containing div if you want the *divs* to appear below each other.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `float` on the DIV. Otherwise this won't work

Comment: Even with the containing div floating, `display: block` will make the input appear below the label. Keeping the `float` would let multiple label/input pairs appear side-by-side, though.

Comment: that's the problem. The title asks that the DIVs be below each other as well. Not side by side.

Comment: Hmm. The title does say that, doesn't it? No hint of that in the question, though...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I marked this correct as it is the first solution that was posted and that worked. Wish I could mark more as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Why not remove the float on the DIV and make the LABEL a block?

```
<div style=" padding-right: 1%;">
  <label class="editor-label" style='display:block;' for="BrowserTitle">Browser Title</label>
  <input class="editor-field" id="BrowserTitle" name="Question.BrowserTitle" size="30" type="text" value="Test title" />
</div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/h7mnJ/

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `label` and the `input` in their own `div`s or set each to `display: block` in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

put label inside a div:

```
<div style="float: left; padding-right: 1%;">  
<div>  
  <label class="editor-label" for="BrowserTitle">Browser Title</label>
<div>
<input class="editor-field" id="BrowserTitle" name="Question.BrowserTitle" size="30" type="text" value="Test title" />
```

See the results at:  http://jsfiddle.net/uUEn8/
Also you can set `display:block` on either label or input.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `display: block` on the label:

```
.editor-label {
    display: block;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/b5UrP/

Or you could float both the label and input to the left and put `clear: left` on the input:

```
.editor-label {
    float: left;
}
.editor-field {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hxhCx/

Answer (score 0):

As all of the CSS solutions have been exhausted, here's a HTML solution with the `<br />` element:

```
<div style="float: left; padding-right: 1%;">
  <label class="editor-label" for="BrowserTitle">Browser Title</label>
  <br />
  <input class="editor-field" id="BrowserTitle" name="Question.BrowserTitle" size="30" type="text" value="Test title" />
</div>
```